# How to minimise a multivariate cost function in Julia with Optim?

Tags: optimization, julia, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am currently stuck trying to utilize the Optim package in Julia in an attempt to minimize a cost function. The cost function is the cost function for an L2 regularised logistic regression. It is constructed as follows;

```
using Optim

function regularised_cost(X, y, θ, λ)
    m = length(y)

    # Sigmoid predictions
    h = sigmoid(X * θ)

    # left side of the cost function
    positive_class_cost = ((-y)' * log.(h))

    # right side of the cost function
    negative_class_cost = ((1 .- y)' * log.(1 .- h))

    # lambda effect
    lambda_regularization = (λ/(2*m) * sum(θ[2 : end] .^ 2))

    # Current batch cost
     = (1/m) * (positive_class_cost - negative_class_cost) + lambda_regularization

    # Gradients for all the theta members with regularization except the constant
    ∇ = (1/m) * (X') * (h-y) + ((1/m) * (λ * θ))  

    ∇[1] = (1/m) * (X[:, 1])' * (h-y) # Exclude the constant

    return (, ∇)
end
```

I would like to use LBFGS algorithm as a solver to find the best weights that minimize this function based on my training examples and labels which are defined as:

```
opt_train = [ones(size(X_train_scaled, 1)) X_train_scaled] # added intercept
initial_theta = zeros(size(opt_train, 2))
```

Having read the documentation, here's my current implementation which is currently not working:

```
cost, gradient! = regularised_cost(opt_train, y_train, initial_theta, 0.01)

res = optimize(regularised_cost,
               gradient!,
               initial_theta,
               LBFGS(),
               Optim.Options(g_tol = 1e-12,
                             iterations = 1000,
                             store_trace = true,
                             show_trace = true))
```

How do I pass my training examples and labels along with the gradients so that the solver (LBFGS) can find me the best weights for theta?

Answer (score 2):

You need to close over your train data and make a loss function that only takes the parameters as inputs.

As per the docs on [dealing with constant parameterised](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/#user/tipsandtricks/)

It should be so.wthing like:

```
loss_and_grad(theta) = regularised_cost(opt_train, y_train, theta, 0.01)

loss(theta) = first(loss_and_grad(theta))

res = optimize(loss, initial_theta)
```

I will leave it to you to see how to hook the gradient in.

A reminder though: don't use non-const globals.
They are slow,  in particular the way they are used in the `loss_and_grad` function I wrote will be slow.
So you should declare `opt_train` and `y_train` as `const`.
Or make a function that takes them and returns a loss function etc